# Converting Swift 1.2 code to Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I've tried for 15 minutes trying to figure out how to use this code from a book which was written before Swift 2, in an Xcode 7 app in Swift 2. Here's the code snippit:

```
    self.coreMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.3
self.coreMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {

    (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in

        if let constVar = error { 

 println("There was an error")
         }
         else {

             self.xAxisAcceleration = CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x)
         } })
```

I get the error: "Cannot invoke 'startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue' with an argument list of type '(NSOperationQueue, withHandler: (CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> _)'

Comment: Do you really format your code like that? Readability matters.

Comment: @zaph No, I did the best I could with my iPhone, as there is no Wi-Fi where I'm staying, so I can't use my Mac.

Comment: @matt I typed it EXACTLY as it appeared in the book in Swift 1.2 in order to not confuse anyone. Question updated with error info.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Off-topic but you can always open a wifi hotspot on your phone and join it on the iMac :) 

Comment: @HAS Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, because I'm on Straight Talk, I cannot use the Personal Hotspot on my iPhone.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Oh! I didn't know there were any limitations! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the iOS SDK has been further audited for nullability, so those parameters which are implicitly unwrapped in the code sample from your book, are plain old optionals now (i.e. use `?` rather than `!`):

```
coreMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.3
coreMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) { (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    guard data != nil else {
        print("There was an error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    self.xAxisAcceleration = CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x)
}
```

Or, more simply, let the compiler infer the types of the closure parameters:

```
coreMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.3
coreMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) { data, error in
    guard data != nil else {
        print("There was an error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    self.xAxisAcceleration = CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x)
}
```

And, as you see above, since you're using Swift 2, you might as well as use the `guard` syntax, too.

Comment: BTW, if you're looking at a lot of Swift 1.2 code, you'll probably see a lot of this sort of problem. If you do, you can either use "code completion" in Xcode (and it will show you what type the parameters are) or refer to the documentation for the method in question (drilling into the closure type of `CMAccelerometerHandler`). Either way, just drill into the parameters of the Cocoa methods and/or of closure parameters, and double check the nullability (i.e. review optionals). good luck!